# how to compress a blob column using utl_compress.lz_compress and insert it to another table

Tags: oracle, compression, blob

I'm new to oracle pl sql.
There is a table(tableA)  with a blob column,i want to get this column, compress it using utl_compress.lz_compress(blob_column) and then insert this column in 'tableB',using procedure.
I try some ways to do this but i get 'bad argument' error.
Thank you very much.

> EDIT : I need some thing like this

```
procedure myProcedure as
 begin  
  FOR myrectype IN (SELECT * FROM  tableA) 
  LOOP
  insert into tableB(id,blob_column) values(myrectype.id,utl_compress.lz_compress(myrectype.blob_column));
  END LOOP

 end myProcedure;
```

> Exception :

```
29261. 00000 -  "bad argument"
*Cause:    A bad argument was passed to the PL/SQL API.
*Action:   Check the arguments passed to the PL/SQL API and retry the call.
others exception with code :  -29261
others exception with mssg :  ORA-29261: bad argumen
```

Comment: It is always helpful to post the code you wrote and the error stack you got (the exact Oracle error message and the error stack that shows the line where the error was thrown).

Comment: @JustinCave ,Thank you for reply,I added a sample that i need,in above sample i get 'ORA-29261: bad argument'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that.need to store utl_compress.lz_compress(myrectype.blob_column) in a variable first.I Changed procedure to :

```
procedure myProcedure as
v_blob_column blob;
 begin  
  FOR myrectype IN (SELECT * FROM  tableA) 
  LOOP
  v_blob_column := utl_compress.lz_compress(myrectype.blob_column);
  insert into tableB(id,blob_column) values(myrectype.id,v_blob_column);
  END LOOP

end myProcedure;
```

Thanks